# Heap Debugging: Assert failure in dbgdel in MS VC++ 2005

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2005

I enabled Heap Debugging in my MS VC++ 2005 project and as the program exits out of the last destructor, I put a call to _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() there (also enabled _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC. But then I saw the following debug assertion screen:

[image]

Following that I hit Retry to debug it and it takes me to some code (this isn't mine) where I see stuff like:

```
char* name;
cstub.get("...", name);
delete [] name;
```

I am thinking to myself that perhaps name was allocated inside the get(..) function; anyway, my question is: from the screen shot is this a memory/heap bug? I probably have to dig into what cstub's get function is doing. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Yes, it's a heap error.  Probably memory was freed that wasn't allocated from the heap or something overwrote memory on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

You might be mixing runtimes.

If the allocator is in a DLL that was compiled with a different version of Visual Studio, then you cannot release the memory from your code.

This is why libraries that return allocated memory also include functions or methods to release that memory.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Great point. I think that is why I am seeing this error. But it also raises the question of how I can go about diagnosing the memory heap error I have? My solution (plugin in an application) has like 21 projects and links to 3rd party libraries. If I have to ensure each and every one has Code Generation set to /MDd, this becomes an impossible problem!